# GROUP BY between dates to count unique users returns more than expected

Tags: sql

Using the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) I'm trying to figure out how many different users asked questions between 19 October 2012 and 9 November 2012. I've gotten my query to this:

```
SELECT Count(*)
FROM Posts
WHERE (CreationDate BETWEEN '2012-10-19' AND '2012-11-09') AND PostTypeId = 1
GROUP BY OwnerUserId
```

However, this returns 3,071 rows on Super User (I'm not going to try it on Stack Overflow). This seems way too high. Am I missing something?

Comment: What range were you expecting?

Comment: FWIW: there were 51,747 new users on Super User during that time frame...

Comment: @random Not three grand!

Comment: @Shog9 Oh for the love of Aunt Jemima, are you for real? Dang! Maybe 3k is right after all!

Comment: Skipping the GROUP BY shows that there were 4671 posts in that time frame, so 3071 users sounds about right.

Comment: Also, do you want to include *closed questions?* If not, add `AND ClosedDate IS NULL` and you get 2726 rows.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you just want to get a simple count of the distinct users, you can use the `DISTINCT` keyword like this:

```
SELECT Count(DISTINCT OwnerUserID)
FROM Posts
WHERE (CreationDate BETWEEN '2012-10-19' AND '2012-11-09') AND PostTypeId = 1
```

The distinct keyword will ensure that you only count each OwnerUserID once - the original question will just return the number of questions that each distinct user asked (which is fairly useless without additional context).

In effect, this query returns a count of the number of rows returned in the original query.

Answer (score 2):

The SQL in question returns the count for each group-- the group by is telling SQL to output a row for each group, which is not what (I understood) you want. You want a single count of the distinct user id's

```
select count(distinct OwnerUserId)
from Posts
WHERE (CreationDate BETWEEN '2012-10-19' AND '2012-11-09') AND PostTypeId = 1
```

Comment: The SQL in question returns the count for each group-- the group by is telling SQL to output a row for each group, which is not what you want.  You want a single count of the distinct user id's.

Comment: Your explanatory comment should be added to the answer as all you've done so far is a code dump

Answer (score 2):

If all you want is the total number of *distinct* users, then you can use the `distnct` keyword as part of your `Count` and then leave out the `GROUP BY`

For example

```
SELECT Count(DISTINCT OwnerUserId)
FROM Posts
WHERE (CreationDate BETWEEN '2012-10-19' AND '2012-11-09') AND PostTypeId = 1
```